# Input form to create content type(s)

Tags: forms, nodes, webforms

**Use Case**

We will have users submitting forms that will then be mapped to one of three content types based on the information they've entered.  We don't want to burden the user with trying determine what content type to use on their own.  They should just enter the data and then we'll make the call based on that.

**Best Approach**

The way I see us doing this is creating a webform that we then hook into with a custom module that programatically creates the new nodes of the appropriate content type.

I wanted to check with the brain trust here that this makes sense for our use case and there isn't a module to use that makes more sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a fine solution. The one thing I would suggest is to NOT use the webform module. I think you should just create the custom form with the [Form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7).

You'll spend more time overriding the unneeded behavior and features of webform than you would creating the form from scratch with FAPI.

Comment: The nice thing about using webform vs the form api is that we have non-developers who are perfectly capable of creating the forms via webform and iterating through them with the clients.

I haven't found them that hard to hook into in the past, but I've also hooked in for very simple purposes thus far.

Comment: Yeah, the GUI for webform is great. It still doesn't seem right to use webform though, because it has a very specific purpose. You might want to checkout [Form Builder](http://drupal.org/project/form_builder) (by the same author as webform)."*The task of actually building the form was secondary to the task of using the form. This is where the Form builder project comes in.*"